# How to customize the TypeDoc theme?

Tags: typedoc

Looking at the default TypeDoc theme. They say it is to customize however I just cannot get how/what should I update to get the view like the one on the screenshot (attached) out of the default one?
[what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyhfM.png)
Is it even possible?

This is all I was able to do so far:
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqX2X.png)